# Proposal for two tags: [intelligence-service] and [secret-service]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

#### Summary

I propose adding two tags: [intelligence-service](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intelligence-service) and [secret-service](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/secret-service).

The [intelligence-service](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intelligence-service) tag complements the existing tags: [espionage](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/espionage), [surveillance](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/surveillance), [intelligence](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intelligence) and [counterintelligence](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counterintelligence), as well as tags for [cia](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cia) and [nsa](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nsa).

The excerpt for [intelligence-service](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intelligence-service) could be,

> Questions about intelligence gathering organizations within a government. Use with an appropriate country tag.

The excerpt for [secret-service](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/secret-service) could be,

> Questions about the US Secret Service, which provides certain protective services for certain dignitaries and protects the integrity of the US currency. Use with the [united-states] tag. For organizations within a government that act in secret, see [intelligence-service].

---

#### Tag editing

There are currently [23 questions](https://politics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22secret+service%22+is%3Aq) using "secret service". Three of those questions do not refer to the US. About five questions are actually *about* the US Secret Service. The rest are mere mentions.

Concerning *intelligence service* or *agency*, of the more than fifty questions, several are tagged [espionage](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/espionage), [surveillance](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/surveillance), or [intelligence](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intelligence), though the questions are *about* the service or agency. I do not, at this time, know how many questions would use the [intelligence-service](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intelligence-service) tag; but there are some.

Examples:

- [What are the implications of allowing politicization of intelligence services?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/48762/26455)
- [When can one U.S. agency ask for intelligence or information from another U.S. agency?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/66329/26455)

---

Additional research

#### Definitions, excerpts and Wikipedia links

##### Secret service

The term, [secret service](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/secret%20service), may refer to,

1. a governmental service of a secret nature
2. a division of the U.S. Department of Homeland Security ...

Wikipedia, *[Secret service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secret_service)*,

> A **secret service** is a government agency, intelligence agency, or the activities of a government agency, concerned with the gathering of intelligence data.

##### Intelligence service

There are more than fifty questions ([intelligence service](https://politics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22intelligence%22+service+is%3Aq+): 21, and [intelligence agency](https://politics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22intelligence%22+agency+is%3Aq+): 37) mentioning the terms.

Wikipedia, *[Intelligence agency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligence_agency)*,

> An **intelligence agency** is a government agency responsible for the collection, analysis, and exploitation of information in support of law enforcement, national security, military, and foreign policy objectives.

- The choice for [intelligence-service](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intelligence-service) over [intelligence-agency](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intelligence-agency) comes from the wider use of "intelligence service" as shown in [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=intelligence+agency%2Cintelligence+service&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3). In addition to "English (2019)" also look at "French (2019)", "German (2019)", "Russian (2019)", etc.

##### Intelligence

[intelligence](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intelligence) tag (26 questions) for,

> Questions related to strategic, technical and policy information.

Wikipedia, *[Military intelligence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_intelligence)*,

> **Military intelligence** is a military discipline that uses information collection and analysis approaches to provide guidance and direction to assist commanders in their decisions.

And *[Strategic intelligence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategic_intelligence)*,

> **Strategic intelligence** (STRATINT) pertains to the collection, processing, analysis, and dissemination of intelligence that is required for forming policy and military plans at the national and international level.

##### Espionage

[espionage](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/espionage) tag (27 questions) as,

> Espionage (also called spying) is the process states use to gather intelligence on each other. Use with specific country tags.

Wikipedia, *[Espionage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espionage)*,

> **Espionage**, **spying** or **intelligence gathering** is the act of obtaining secret or confidential information (intelligence) from non-disclosed sources or divulging of the same without the permission of the holder of the information for a tangible benefit.

##### Surveillance

[surveillance](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/surveillance) tag (24 questions) with no usage guidance.

Wikipedia, *[Surveillance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surveillance)*,

> **Surveillance** is the monitoring of behavior, many activities, or information for the purpose of information gathering, influencing, managing or directing.

##### Counterintelligence

[counterintelligence](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/counterintelligence) tag (2 questions) as

> Counterintelligence is an activity aimed at protecting an agency's intelligence program against an opposition's intelligence service.

The excerpt was copied from Wikipedia, *[Counterintelligence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterintelligence)*.

Comment: `+1` I'm in favor of both. It might be worth considering the name protective-service instead of secret-service as it is less US-centric and describes the function better. I'm sure there are plenty of government agencies that provide a wide and disparate variety of services that happen to be secret but shouldn't be lumped together under one tag just because of that.

Comment: @uhoh - [tag:private-military-companies] also provide "protective services". They may be hired by governments, companies or individuals; but they are not a government "service". I think the presence of the [tag:united-states] tag on such questions and the excerpt would help indicate that it is not a tag to be used generally.

Comment: good point! It's just a suggestion to reduce mistagging mistakes, I'm fine with any permutation. I suppose there's also governmental-protective-service to resolve that conflict.

Comment: I see the secret-service tag now exists and has been added to a question. Perhaps this meta question should now have an answer, or alternatively moderators sometimes add the status-completed tag to the question, something to indicate that action has been taken and in one form or another a decision has been made.

Comment: @uhoh - I'll take care of it in a few days. Some may take notice of the changes and post a comment on the post on Meta that need be addressed. There were not a lot of views.